# Restrict four table columns to different values in Firebird DBMS

Tags: sql, database, validation, firebird

I have a table with 4 unique columns

I tried stuff like this:

```
ALTER TABLE "FolderDsg" ADD CONSTRAINT CHK4_FOLDERDSG CHECK (ORDER2 = ORDER3) 
ALTER TABLE "FolderDsg" ADD CONSTRAINT CHK11_FOLDERDSG CHECK (ORDER1 not in (ORDER2)) 
ALTER TABLE "FolderDsg" ADD CONSTRAINT CHK13_FOLDERDSG CHECK (ORDER1 like (ORDER2)) 
/******************************************************************************/ 
/*                             Unique Constraints                             */ 
/******************************************************************************/ 
ALTER TABLE "FolderDsg" ADD CONSTRAINT UNQ1_FOLDERDSG UNIQUE (ORDER1) 
USING INDEX "_IDXORDER1"
```

It works for every column. But how can I create a unique for all 4 columns?

```
+------+------+------+------+
|Order1|Order2|Order3|Order4| 
+------+------+------+------+
|1     |2     |3     |4     | = valid OK Check
+------+------+------+------+
|5     |5     |6     |7     | = not valid ( That works in the Database ) 
+------+------+------+------+
|8     |9     |10    |11    | = valid OK Check 
+------+------+------+------+
|12    |13    |9     |14    | = valid  ( That's the Problem ) I need a not valid 
+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: Removed `sql-server` tag - this question is about **Firebird** - not (Microsoft) **SQL Server**

Comment: Why should the last one be not valid? If you want values to be unique over all columns and all rows, then you might have the wrong table structure.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
ALTER TABLE "FolderDsg" ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK (ORDER1 not in (ORDER2, ORDER3, ORDER4) and
                                              ORDER2 not in (ORDER3, ORDER4) and
                                              ORDER3 not in (ORDER4)
                                             );
```

EDIT:

If you also want the values unique  within a column, you can add four unique constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE "FolderDsg" ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (ORDER1);
ALTER TABLE "FolderDsg" ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (ORDER2);
ALTER TABLE "FolderDsg" ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (ORDER3);
ALTER TABLE "FolderDsg" ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (ORDER4);
```

EDIT II;

And, if you really want all the values in all the columns to be different, you have two choices.  The first is to use a `before update`/`before insert` trigger.  The second is much preferable:  store the data in a normalized format.

Create a table that has one row per "FolderDsg" and order:

```
create table FolderDsgOrder (
    FolderDsgId int,
    OrderNum int,
    OrderValue int
    /* whatever else you want goes here */
);
```

Now you can create the simple constraint:

```
alter table FolderDsgOrder add constraint unique (OrderValue);
```

Comment: This should work ok, unless columns also allow NULL values. In such case you would need to use IS DISTINCT FROM.

Comment: @MilanBabuškov . . . Good point.  I do note that the sample data in the question does not have any NULL values.

Comment: I just re-read the question, and it appears he wants values to be unique across all columns AND rows. See my answer.

Comment: @MilanBabuškov . . . I don't read it that way.  But I do note that the value `9` is considered valid in both `Order2` and `Order3` on different rows.

Comment: Yup, see on the last line where he says it's valid, but he does not want it to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate table holding all the values:

```
CREATE TABLE ALL_VALUES (
    VALUE int not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (VALUE)
);
```

Now, add a trigger to check and update it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER FOR "FolderDsg" AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    -- insert all the values. If any of those already exists, 
    -- the primary key constraint will be violated, and you'll get the error
    INSERT INTO ALL_VALUES VALUES(NEW.ORDER1);
    INSERT INTO ALL_VALUES VALUES(NEW.ORDER2);
    INSERT INTO ALL_VALUES VALUES(NEW.ORDER3);
    INSERT INTO ALL_VALUES VALUES(NEW.ORDER4);
END
```

If you have updates and deletes you will need additional triggers to remove stuff from the ALL_VALUES table.

If values can be NULL, you can use UNIQUE constraint instead of PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution it's close to "Milan Babuškov" hint 
 
THX everyone special Thanks to Milan 
Have a look at 
http://www.delphipraxis.net/178566-unique-bei-4-verschiedenen-feldern-2.html#post1245205